# Importing Gradle Project stuck at Build model

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to import a Gradle Project for the second time(the 1.16.5 Forge Minecraft MDK). This morning all was working well, and for a silly thing I delete in the disk the project, so I tried to import again my project but the loading is stuck at Import root project : Build model 'org.eclipse.xxx' for root
So I didn't find anything, I unistall-reinstall Gradle, and my project, and it doesn't working !
Thanks in advance for your help,
Noctos

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow ! What do you mean with "doesn't work" ? Do you have logs ?

Comment: The project is always stuck at "Build model 'org.eclipse.xxxxx.RunClosedProjectxxxxx'
However, I checked in the .log

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.